# MySQL Table Relationships - One to One and Many to Many

Tags: mysql, database, relationships

I am trying to figure out if I have a good database structure to pass a value from the `source_name` from my `source` table to the `source_name` from my `post` table. It seems like if it were possible, it would involve a good amount of table joins and complexity to achieve, but I feel like there might be a better way to connect the two tables.

**Current Relationships**

user & post = *One-to-One*

(user/organization) & Member = *Many-to-Many*

organization & source = *One-to-One*

[image: relationships]

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: Organization and Member is a Many-to-Many so Post and Source is also a Many to Many. You cannot possibly store the value as a column in the post table.

Comment: @microtony thank you for your answer. As a result, how would you re-organize the relationships so that this value could be populated in both source and post? A scenario I have is that when an organization registers they set predefined sources (infographic, long read, etc.) that can then be selected from a dropdown by a user and used as a value connected to the post

Comment: You can add a one-to-many relationship between source and post.